# Drools 6 - Accessing the LHS of an ObjectInsertedEvent

Tags: drools, event-listener

I'm in the process of upgrading from Drools 5.5.0.Final to Drools 6.5.0.CR2, and I'm running into a problem with a custom event listener that listens for ObjectInsertedEvents and references the LHS of the rule that triggered the insertion. Depending on the types of the LHS bindings of the fired rule, the listener updates a property of the newly inserted fact.

In Drools 5, we did this with a custom event listener that extended DebugWorkingMemoryEventListener and implemented WorkingMemoryEventListener:

```
public void objectInserted(ObjectInsertedEvent event) {
    Rule firedRule = event.getPropagationContext().getRuleOrigin();

    if (firedRule !=  null) {
        PropagationContext pc = event.getPropagationContext();
        Tuple tuple = pc.getLeftTupleOrigin();
        Map<String, Declaration> declarationsMap = firedRule.getDeclarations();

        // Iterate through the LHS variable bindings
        for (Map.Entry<String, Declaration> entry : declarationsMap.entrySet()) {

            // Get the value, via the handle to the fact in working memory to which the variable is bound
            Declaration declaration = entry.getValue();
            FactHandle factHandle = tuple.get(declaration);

            // Get the object in working memory via the fact handle
            Object bindingObj = ss.getObject(factHandle)

            // do some other checks, update the inserted object if necessary
        }
    }
}
```

WorkingMemoryEventListener is deprecated in Drools 6, so I've updated to RuleRuntimeEventListener, but it looks like I can no longer access the LHS of the rule that fired the ObjectInsertedEvent, only some basic info about the rule itself (name, package, metadata). Alternatively, I could access the LHS of a fired rule with an AgendaEventListener and AfterMatchFiredEvent, but that 1) doesn't tell me if an object was inserted, and 2) doesn't give me a way to update that object even if I could determine if it was inserted.

How can I replicate the listener behavior that I had in Drools 5 with these Drools 6 API changes? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement BeforeMatchFired, AfterMatchFired and ObjectInsertedEvent you can create a Collection of facts inserted during the firing of a rule. The Match object gives you all the bindings from the rule's LHS. All inserted objects are available and should be processed at the AfterMatchFired event.

I don't see anything that keeps you from porting your code to 6.x, with only moderate additional code for maintaining the Collection.