# How to get all the facts in the LHS of a rule which is fired and contains insert in the RHS?

Tags: java, drools

How to get all the facts in the LHS of a rule which is fired when the rule insert a new object in the RHS? I'm a new learner in Drools. And now I'm using Drools 7. A rule is as follows.

```
rule "Hello World"
when
    $ms:MiddleSchool()
then
    System.out.println("ruleName is Hello World");
    HighSchool hs = new HighSchool();
    hs.setNum(10);
    insert(hs);
end
```

And I write an `eventListener` but it can't get the LHS of the rule.

```
public class RunListener implements RuleRuntimeEventListener{
  @Override
  public void objectInserted(ObjectInsertedEvent objectInsertedEvent){
  }
}
```

So I really hope someone can teach me how to write the `eventListener` to get the LHS of a rule while there exists insert in the RHS of the rule and the rule is fired.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a tricky one. First of all, let me tell you that not all `ObjectInsertedEvents` are associated to a rule. You can insert a fact yourself using a `KieSession` reference.

Unfortunately, what you are trying to do is not straightforward in Drools. You need the combination of 2 listeners and the assumption that rules activations are executed in sequence (which I think is the default behavior).

In addition to your `RuleRuntimeEventListener` you will also need to register an instance of `AgendaEventListener` to your session.
This listener will be invoked - among other times- when a rule is about to be fired (`BeforeMatchFiredEvent`) and after a rule was fired (`AfterMatchFiredEvent`).

So now you have 3 pieces of information (the order here is important):

- Rule-X was about to be fired -> From `AgendaEventListener`
- And Object was inserted and `ObjectInsertedEvent.rule.name == "Rule-X"` -> From `RuleRuntimeEventListener`
- Rule-X was fired -> From `AgendaEventListener`

Unfortunately, as far as I know, the only way to relate these 3 events is the name of the rule.

From the `BeforeMatchFiredEvent` you can get all the facts involved in the activation of the rule by doing `event.getMatch().getObjects()`. If you are only interested in the bound objects of the LHS of the rule, you can try with `event.getMatch().getDeclarationIds()` and `event.getMatch().getDeclarationValue()`.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thank you for your careful response! It seems that there is no way to get the LHS of a triggered rule from your idea. However, the question in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39713923/drools-6-accessing-the-lhs-of-an-objectinsertedevent?rq=1 maybe a reference. But I can't make it run correctly.

Comment: The response in that thread is exactly the same I'm providing here: a combination of 2 event listeners. Now, with this approach, you will get **the facts that made your rule fire** and not the LHS (patterns and conditionals) of the rule that fired.

Comment: Ok, I will have a try again. Thanks a lot! In fact, I have tried as the thread I offered here before. But I failed because there was some grammatical mistake while copied the code to eclipse.

Comment: I tested the code as what you said. However, I can get all the facts that made my rule fired including the insert by kSession in the DroolsTest.java and update in my rule. I think I have made some mistakes in detail. Since I don't know how to write codes in the objectInserted method. Codes in eclipse are as follows in detail.

Comment: I write my code in detail as a new answer since I can't copied here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
The main code is as follows.

public class DroolsTest {
public static final void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
        KieContainer kieContainer = ks.getKieClasspathContainer();
        KieSession kSession = kieContainer.newKieSession("ksession-rules");
        AgendaEventListener agendaEventListener = new AgendaEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void afterMatchFired(AfterMatchFiredEvent arg0) {
                 System.out.println("##############");
                 System.out.println(arg0.getMatch().getObjects());
                 System.out.println(arg0.getMatch().getDeclarationIds());
                 System.out.println(arg0.getMatch().getRule());
                 System.out.println("###############");
            }

            @Override
            public void afterRuleFlowGroupActivated(RuleFlowGroupActivatedEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
            @Override
            public void afterRuleFlowGroupDeactivated(RuleFlowGroupDeactivatedEvent arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void agendaGroupPopped(AgendaGroupPoppedEvent arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void agendaGroupPushed(AgendaGroupPushedEvent arg0) {
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeMatchFired(BeforeMatchFiredEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("***************");
                System.out.println(arg0.getMatch().getObjects());
                System.out.println(arg0.getMatch().getDeclarationIds());
                System.out.println(arg0.getMatch().getRule());
                System.out.println("***************");
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeRuleFlowGroupActivated(RuleFlowGroupActivatedEvent arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeRuleFlowGroupDeactivated(RuleFlowGroupDeactivatedEvent arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void matchCancelled(MatchCancelledEvent arg0) {
            }
            @Override
            public void matchCreated(MatchCreatedEvent arg0) {
            }
        };

        kSession.addEventListener(agendaEventListener);
        Product p1 = new Product();
        p1.setDiscount(10);
        kSession.insert(p1);//I think insert here would influence the insert in my rule and the eventListener would grasp it.

        Message message = new Message();
        message.setMessage("Hello World");
        message.setStatus(Message.HELLO);
        kSession.insert(message);//disturbed insert which would influence insert in my  rule.

        int count = kSession.fireAllRules();
        System.out.println("number of fired rules:" + count + "H");
        kSession.dispose();
       } catch (Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
 public static class Message {
    public static final int HELLO = 0;
    public static final int GOODBYE = 1;
    private String message;
    private int status;

    public String getMessage() {
        return this.message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public int getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }
    public void setStatus(int status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

}

This is RuleRuntimeEventListener.

```
package com.sample;
import org.kie.api.event.rule.ObjectDeletedEvent;
import org.kie.api.event.rule.ObjectInsertedEvent;
import org.kie.api.event.rule.ObjectUpdatedEvent;
import org.kie.api.event.rule.RuleRuntimeEventListener;

public class RunListener implements RuleRuntimeEventListener {
    @Override
    public void objectInserted(ObjectInsertedEvent objectInsertedEvent) {
        System.out.println("监听insert对象");//how to write the method?
        System.out.println(objectInsertedEvent.getObject());
    }
    @Override
    public void objectDeleted(ObjectDeletedEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("监听delete对象");
    }
    @Override
    public void objectUpdated(ObjectUpdatedEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("监听update对象");
    }
}
```

This is my rule.

```
package com.sample
import com.sample.DroolsTest.Message;
import java.util.Map;
rule "Hello World"
no-loop true
    when
        m1 : (Message( status == Message.HELLO))
        $p1:Product(discount==10)
    then
        System.out.println(drools.getRule().getName());
        m1.setMessage( "Goodbye cruel world" );
        m1.setStatus( Message.GOODBYE );        
        Product p2 = new Product();
        p2.setDiscount(20);
        insert(p2);
end
rule "GoodBye"
no-loop true
    when
        $p2:Product(discount==20)
    then
        System.out.println(drools.getRule().getName());
end
rule "updateName"
no-loop true
    when
        $p2:Product(discount==20)
    then
        $p2.setDiscount(30);
        update($p2);
        System.out.println(drools.getRule().getName());
end
```

This is a class used in my rule.

```
package com.sample;
public class Product {
    private int discount;
    public Product() {
        super();
    }
    public Product(int discount) {
        super();
        this.discount = discount;
    }
    public int getDiscount() {
        return discount;
    }
    public void setDiscount(int discount) {
        this.discount = discount;
    }
}
```